# How to get colums from two tables SQL

Tags: sql

I have created a database that has several tables.

the tables that are relevant to my problem:

Profile table
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/profileqw.jpg/
Stores all the porfiles

SalaryGroup table
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/255/salarygroup.jpg/
Stores all the salaries

ProfileSalaryGroups
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/138/profileandsalary.jpg/
Stores the profiles and salaries that are connected

I have several stored procedures that insert profiles/salaries etc. I have a procedure that connects the profiles and salaries and stores them in the "profileSalaryGroups" table.
I also have a procedure that gets all the salaries that are connected to a specific profile.

These prrocedures perform the following:

Connects profiles & salaries procedure(Works perfectly):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ConnectProfileAndSalary]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ProfileName varchar(50) = '', 
    @Salaryname varchar(50) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @pId int
    DECLARE @sId int
    SELECT @pId =  Id from [Profile] where Name = @ProfileName
    SELECT @sId =  Id from SalaryGroup where Name = @Salaryname

    -- If the Id number already exists
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProfileSalaryGroups WHERE SalaryGroupId = @sId) > 0 OR
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProfileSalaryGroups WHERE ProfileId = @pId) > 0)  
        RAISERROR ('Connection Exists', -- Message text.
                    16, -- Severity.
                    1 )
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO ProfileSalaryGroups (SalaryGroupId,ProfileId ) VALUES (@sId, @pId)
END
```

Gets all salaries that are connected to a specific profile(Works perfectly):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetConnectedSalaries]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ProfId int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT SalaryGroupId, s.Name from ProfileSalaryGroups ps
    INNER JOIN SalaryGroup as s on s.Id = ps.SalaryGroupId
    Where ps.ProfileId = @ProfId
END
```

**Problem:**

I am trying to create a procedure that gets me all the salarie Id's and Names that are NOT
Connected to a profile.

I have tried several approaches to this, example:

```
SELECT SalaryGroupId, s.Name from ProfileSalaryGroups ps
    INNER JOIN SalaryGroup as s on s.Id = ps.SalaryGroupId
    Where ps.ProfileId != @ProfId
```

this gets me half of the things that i want. I want to get ALL the salaries that are not connected to this profile but this code returns me all the salary Id's and names that have a connection to a profile but not to the one that i sent as a parameter, it does not include all of the salaries that exists in the "SalaryGroup" table

```
SELECT s.Id, s.Name from SalaryGroup s
    where NOT EXISTS (SELECT SalaryGroupId, s.Name, s.Id from ProfileSalaryGroups ps
    INNER JOIN SalaryGroup as s on s.Id = ps.SalaryGroupId
    Where ps.ProfileId = 17
    )
```

This returned nothing.

Iv'e been at this for a while and attempted several other approaches(in some case laughable ) and I'm stuck, If more info is needed then ask and i will do my best to provide it.

If the title was not correct then I'm sorry but I did not know what to make of the title for this problem. If @Admin has a better title in mind then feel free to change it.

Thank you!

Comment: It is complicated :D. Please refine your question.

Comment: Well basicly I need to get Salary Id's and names of those salaries that are not connected to a specific profile. example:

At the html page you crate a profile called "test"
this profile gets the id nr 5.

I send this id number as a paramater to my procedure and want to get the name and ID of all those salaries that are not connected to the profile that has the Id number 5, in this example that would be all the salaries since the new profile would just have been created and not connected to any salaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your parameter as condition for LEFT JOIN and check `ps.SalaryGroupId IS NULL` in WHERE clause

```
SELECT s.Id, s.Name 
FROM SalaryGroup as s LEFT JOIN ProfileSalaryGroups ps on s.Id = ps.SalaryGroupId
                                  AND ps.ProfileId = @ProfId
WHERE ps.SalaryGroupId IS NULL
```

Comment: Tested this a few times just 2 be sure and it works perfectly! thanks!

If you would be kind and explain the last  lines of code i would be greatfull!

Comment: look at Visual Representation of SQL Joins http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins. Specifically on Left Excluding JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a left join and look for where the right hand side of the join has no results:

```
SELECT 
  s.Id, 
  s.Name 
from SalaryGroup  s
left JOIN ProfileSalaryGroups as ps 
on s.Id = ps.SalaryGroupId
Where ps.SalaryGroupId is null
```

This should get *all* the salary ids and names, but remove where there is a matching record in SalaryGroup (ie where s.profileId is not null)

Comment: profileId does not exists in SalaryGroup
check pic:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/255/salarygroup.jpg/

Comment: fair enough, general approach should work for your problem though. I've modified the SQL a bit to hopefully work

Answer (score 0):

Left outer join should do what you want:

```
select * 
   from SalaryGroup sal
   left outer join ProfileSalaryGroups prof on
        prof.Id = sal.Id
   where prof.Id is null or prof.ProfileId != @ProfId
```

**Explanation:** where `prof.Id is null` selects those with no profile at all, while `prof.ProfileId != @ProfId` selects those who have a profile but not matching the current one.

Comment: The first attempt that I described in my question got me all salaries that HAVE a connection but not to the profile that i have as a paramater. 

The code that you have provided me got me the other half of the puzzle... It got me all the salaries that DO NOT HAVE a connection what so ever. 

I need both the ones that have a connection to a profile BUT not the profile that i have as a paramater AND the ones that don't have a connection what so ever

Comment: @user1862808, in that case you can just use both conditions.  See the update.

Answer (score 0):

Start simple and work up to you problem.

First, get all salaryID's

```
select * 
from SalaryGroup s
left join ProfileSalaryGroup ps on ps.salaryGroupID=s.ID
```

Now, you don't want them all, so look at ways to eliminate some of them..
To eliminate groups matching the parameter, add a where clause

```
where ps.profileID <> @parameter
```

Now if you want to eliminate salaryGroups without matching Profiles and the following

```
and ps.ProfileID is NULL
```

The left join (rather than INNER JOIN) tells SQL to always return a row, whether or not there is matching data in the second table.   If SQL doesn't find a match, the data column from the second table will all be NULL.   The first part of the WHERE clause only returns rows not matching the parameter.   The second part returns rows with no Profile Salary data